# Control line wrap for python in VS Code

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

For some reason I can't get VS Code to disable line wrap on format. My settings contain these entries

```
"python.formatting.provider": "autopep8",
"python.formatting.autopep8Args": [
    "--max-line-length=200"
],
"python.linting.pep8Args": [
    "--max-line-length=200"
]
```

`editor.wordWrap` is off by default. When I format the document long lines (>79) get wrapped. I've tried all kinds of combinations to get this to work. I even set the formatting provider to `none` to no avail.

It's as if the python settings are simply not picked up. Setting `"python.linting.enabled": false` still lints my files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out I had `settings.json` file in my `.vscode` folder which was overriding my python settings for my user specific settings.